# How to unsubscribe from a channel using "New Managed Pub/Sub Server" in Servicestack.Redis

Tags: c#, redis, servicestack, servicestack.redis

In the the [New Managed Pub/Sub Server](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis#new-managed-pubsub-server) docs they have shown how to subscribe to channels in the initialization of the pubsubserver. But then how do you unsubscribe from a particular channel later in the program when required?

MY CODE:

```
using ServiceStack.Redis;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;

namespace va.communication
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var clientsManager = new PooledRedisClientManager();

            //subscribe to channels 'messages' and 'queue'
            var redisPubSub = new RedisPubSubServer(clientsManager, "messages","queue")
            {
                OnUnSubscribe = (channel) =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Unsubscribed from channel '{0}'", channel);
                },
                OnMessage = (channel, msg) =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Received '{0}' from channel '{1}'", msg, channel);
                }
            };
            redisPubSub.Start();

            //...
            //other code which takes ~5s after which i want to unsubscribe from 'messages'
            Thread.Sleep(5000); 
            //...

            //no longer require channel 'messages'. what to do here?

            while (true) ;//continue with other code
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling Stop() Or Dispose() will unsubscribe and stop listening to subscribed channels. Use Stop() if you want to start listening again later or Dispose() if you're done with the RedisPubSubManager.

Comment: Stop() isnt working for me. Can you please give a link to a sample code?

Comment: @SagarShah [RedisMqServer](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Server/Messaging/Redis/RedisMqServer.cs#L272) and RedisServerEvents classes use it. Not sure why you're starting it in another thread, it's already runs in a background thread, also leave the channels alone after it's been initialized.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to mythz and a some research this worked for me:

to unsubscribe from 'messages' use this->

```
//reassign channels to just 'queue' removing 'messages' as a channel
redisPubSub.Channels = new string[] {"queue" };
```

to unsubscribe from all channels use this->

```
redisPubSub.Channels = new string[] { };//empty channel array
```